# Serialize class to XML?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have the follow class and the list that holds it:

```
public class Transport
{
    public string TransportType { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public class Coordinates
    {
        public float ID { get; set; }
        public float LocX { get; set; }
        public float LocY { get; set; }
        public float LocZ { get; set; }
        public ObjectState State { get; set; }
        public List<int[]> Connections = new <int[]>();
    }
}

public enum ObjectState
{
    Fly,
    Ground,
    Water
}

public static List<Transport> Tracking = new List<Transport>();
```

How do I serialize the Tracking to XML ?

I know I can use [Serializable] on the list and serialize it to file but I am not sure on how I define it to be saved as XML.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If both of your classes were tagged with the `[Serializable]` attribute, then saving things to a file should be as simple as:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transport));

using(var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Path\\To\\File.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
}
```

**Update**

Sorry, didn't realize you were asking about how to customize the output. That is what the `[XmlAttribute]` and `[XmlElement]` attributes are for:

```
public class Transport
{
    // Store TransportType as an attrribute called Type in the XML
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string TransportType { get; set; }

    // Rest of Implementation
}
```

Comment: My main problem is the format it outputs, How can would I personalize what I want as attribute etc ?

Comment: @Guapo use the `[XmlAttribute]` attribute on properties / fields to set things to serialize as attributes as oppose to Elements. There are many other attributes you can decorate with to control serialization. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx

Comment: @vcsjones thanks, that helps, I had some major difficult converting a list to an element but now i have it all sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You need a stream and a XmlSerializer object, here's an example:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\MyPath", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, myClassInstance);

fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
fs.Dispose();
```

Don't forget to handle errors your own way. And I'm also assuming you want to serialize all your class' properties.