# C# Quiz Game - Qs/As in same file?

Tags: c#

I am creating a quiz game in C# using Windows Forms and my initial idea was to put the questions/answers into an XML file, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<quiz>
</question>
<question>
     <answers>

</question>

// More questions here

</quiz>
```

And I was planning on using a class/object such as this below in the form:

```
class Question
{


var listOfQuestions = new List<Question>();
listOfQuestions.Add(question);
```

I was wondering how I'd go about using a combination of these so that I can easily add new questions/answers and then the form will display the questions in a label and the answers would be on four separate buttons? Perhaps someone can help me with an example for what I would include in the form code/XML file to achieve this?

I also wanted to try and perhaps have different sets of questions for different difficulty levels but not sure how I'd do this either.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would change your XML to <quiz><subquiz><question>what is the capital?</question><answers><wrong>Sydney</wrong><correct>Canberra</correct></answers></subquiz></quiz>. Then you can have multiple subquizes. I am talking about the structure of my example versus the structure of yours, not the actual names.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for stackoverflow because it is too localized, you should post it on codereview.stackexchange

Comment: I agree with Benjamin. Anyway, I would change `correctAnswer/wrongAnswer` by `option`, and add an optional boolean attribute `correct` that defaults to `false`.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Uh what? Since when did "too localized" become synonymous with "belongs on Code Review"?

Comment: @BoltClock It's not, but in this case the OP asked for review on his code and/or how is his implementation of something.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: "how to implement something" belongs here and is not on topic on Code Review. From what I can see this is more of an implementation question than a code review question...

Comment: @BoltClock I mis-phrased myself. I corrected to " how is his implementation of something is". Anyway, you obviously have a lot more stackoverflow experience than me so I'll read about this on meta and if I'm still not satisfied with the answer I'll open a question there.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is a bit off, as you can't have free text **and** child nodes in the same element. This would be a bit more correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<quiz>
    <question id="1" difficulty="1">
        <text>What is the capital city of Australia?</text>
        <answers>
            <wrongAnswer>Sydney</wrongAnswer>
            <correctAnswer>Canberra</correctAnswer>
            <wrongAnswer>Melbourne</wrongAnswer>
            <wrongAnswer>Adelaide</wrongAnswer>
        </answers>
    </question>

    <!-- More questions here  -->

</quiz>
```

I also added a couple of attributes that you could use, as per your other question.

As far as loading these into a Forms project, you'd be best off creating a UserControl that you could bind each question to, although this is a lot easier with WPF. I don't have an example of either ATM, but I could come up with something simple if need be.

Comment: Thanks. It'd be great if you had an example because then once I have a rough idea about how I can do it, I can simply start adding the questions/answers and get them to display on the form. Also, how would I get it so that if a user clicks say the Easy/Medium/Hard difficulty button, it only displays the questions that have difficulty="1", "2" or "3"?

Comment: Why use `<wronganswer>` and `<correctanswer>` instead of `<answer correct="0">` or `<answer correct="1">`?

Comment: @badp Both seem equally valid. It would be relatively easy to find the correct answer with LINQ and the OP's original markup; assuming we had already grabbed the `<question>` element and assigned it to the variable `question`, the `answer` could be found by `var answer = question.Descendant("correctAnswer");`

Comment: @Tieson T. Could you help me out with an example of how I would load the contents of the XML file into a form so that the questions display in a label and answers on a button? I've never worked with XML files in C# before so forgive me for being relatively novice-like.

Comment: @user2084095 Yeah, I can post something today.

Comment: @Tieson T. Thank you, that'd be awfully helpful

Comment: @user2084095 Sorry, I don't really have time I can dedicate to working on this more, but here's an example that should point you in the right direction: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4rl80lflhn6ci2/WindowsFormsApplication1.7z

Comment: @Tieson T. Thaks, that's really helpful, although I'm not sure how I can reposition/resize and format (Colour, font etc.) the buttons that the answers display on inside the flow panel?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can simply extend your Question class with a level flag and [Serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937630/serialize-class-to-xml) your class to XML. And then you can on startup load the XML-file and deserialize it.