# How to write a collection to a file in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a winForms program and I'm fairly new to programming. 
Right now I have an Item class

```
public class Item
{
    public string @Url { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public Item(string @url, string name, double price)
    {
        this.Url = url;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

and throughout the program its stored in a dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, Item>
```

How can i create a new file type (.buf) and make it save the dictionary so it can be opened?

Comment: What is a `.buf` file?  Is there a standard format that you need to write to, or are you creating the format?  In general it's preferred to save to a database, of course.

Comment: Try marking the class as [Serializable] and writing it to a file as in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5937722/808532

Comment: So this is a type of thing databases would be used for. I still haven't quite figured out databases or how to use them, i'm still unclear on what they are actually.

Comment: @user2434321 Databases are used to, well, save data. And preferrably do so efficiently, and let you retrieve the data conveniently as well.

Comment: From what i can tell it is something i will have to learn inevitably how would you recommend i get started? Also I'm assuming databases save data as a physical file as I've heard of them before the cloud era started

Comment: You can serialize a dictionary to disk using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299071/serializing-net-dictionary

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serialize the dictionary to a file, I suggest you refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299071/serializing-net-dictionary) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554186/how-to-serialize-deserialize-to-dictionaryint-string-from-custom-xml-not-us).

**Update**

Be sure to look at all the links as there is more than one way to do this, but this is one way - by following [this](http://code-news.blogspot.co.nz/2007/10/serializable-dictionary-in-c.html) information and adding a public constructor of

```
public Item() { }
```

I could then do the following using XamlServices (you will need to add a reference to System.Xaml in your project):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Item newItem = new Item( "http://foo", "test1", 1.0 );

        var values = new Dictionary<int,Item>();
        values.Add(1,newItem);                        
        using( StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText( "serialized.buf" ) )
        {                
            XamlServices.Save( writer, values );    
        }

        using( StreamReader tr = new StreamReader( "serialized.buf" ) )
        {
            Dictionary<int, Item> result = (Dictionary<int, Item>)XamlServices.Load( tr );
            //do something with dictionary here
            Item retrievedItem = result[1];                
        }                                                         
    }
}
```

For information on databases, refer [here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/faqs/what-is-mysql-database.shtml) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database).
If you want to get started using a database and WinForms I suggest [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial).

For deciding between a flat file and a database, refer to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667850/why-use-mysql-over-flatfiles) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499239/database-vs-flat-text-file-what-are-some-technical-reasons-for-choosing-one-ove).
Sorry about all the links, but the info is out there (I know it is hard to find the right search terms when you are starting out).
In my own experience, whether or not you use a database depends on: -

- the complexity of the operations (queries,create,remove,updates,deletes) you want to do.
- the structure of the data you want to store.
- where the application will run. For example, if it will be an embedded application on a router (I take it your winforms app will not) then a file might be your only option.
- similar to the previous point, how lightweight and self-contained you want your application to be.
- the volume of data to be stored.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var file = File.OpenWrite("myfile.buf"))
foreach (var item in dictionary)
file.WriteLine("[{0} {1}]", item.Key, item.Value);
```

Comment: What about the Dictionary keys, and all the data in the `Item`, all this will do (if you fix the compile errors) is save the Name property to a file.

Comment: Why are you even copying `dict`’s values to a separate array? Just iterate over them in your loop to begin with…

Comment: sorry i didnt test my code, the below would work,
           
Dictionary<string,string> dict =  new Dictionary<string,string>();
            dict.Add("element1key","element1value");
            dict.Add("element2key","element2value");
            dict.Add("element3key","element3value");

            string[] arry= new string[dict.Count];
            dict.Values.CopyTo(arry, 0);
         System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\myfile.buf", arry);

Comment: such a bad answer, please never use this kind of code to acomplish what has been asked

Comment: I still don’t understand why you’re copying the array. Even without taking into account keys, `System.IO.File.WriteLines(filePath, dict.Values);` should work fine, right?

Comment: and what about values with newlines in them?

Comment: i edited my reply, retaining keys and values in the file.
Robert , you mean textual values that have lf/cr in them?

Comment: guys come on, i edited my reply, why it has been downvoted? its tested and working

Comment: Okay, you’re iterating the right way now, but it’s still kind of fragile as a serialization method. (I removed my downvote, by the way)