# ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, jit, aot

In my unity3d game I have the following Dictionary :

```
 public Dictionary<string, List<UpgradeData>> upgradeList;
```

where UpgradeData is a very simple class:

```
public class UpgradeData
{
   public bool lockStatus;
   public bool purchased;

}
```

I read [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/) that you cant use value types as Dictionary keys , but as far as I know sting is not a value type. Therefore the problem must be coming from using a List as the dictionary value. Any idea how to work around this. The code works on both the windows platform and MacOS. I'm trying to serialize this Dictionary using the Binary Formatter. I had similar issues with serializing other classes but I managed to fix that by adding :

```
 if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
        {
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");
        }
```

What do I need to do to serialize the dictionary ?

Edit: Forgot the include the whole class that works with the Dictionary

```
[Serializable]
    public class CharacterUpgradeList
    {

        private UpgradeData[] _upgrade_Data;
        private List<UpgradeData>[] upgData;

        public Dictionary<string, List<UpgradeData>> upgradeList;
        public CharacterUpgradeList()
        {
            upgData = new List<UpgradeData>[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < upgData.Length; i++)
            {
                upgData[i] = new List<UpgradeData> { 
                        new UpgradeData(),
                        new UpgradeData(),
                        new UpgradeData(),
                        new UpgradeData(),
                        new UpgradeData(),
                        new UpgradeData()
                   };
            }

            upgradeList = new Dictionary<string, List<UpgradeData>>
        {
            {"Man",upgData[0]},
            {"Woman",upgData[1]},
            {"Boy",upgData[2]},
            {"Girl",upgData[3]}

        };
        }
    }
```

and then I create an object from the above mentioned class in this class:

```
[Serializable]
class GameData
{
    public int _coinAmount, _upgradeLevel;
    public Level_Data[] _level_Data;
    public CharacterUpgradeList _charUpgradeList;
    public SerialVector2 serialVector;

    public GameData()
    {
        _charUpgradeList = new CharacterUpgradeList(); 
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to serialize GameData.

Comment: just looking at it quickly I would think that you should be able to `Serialize an Object` that being said I would change the method signature to make the second param an object basically by casting the `upgradeList` something like this 
`(IDictionary<string, object>)upgradeList` I am not sure how Mono would handle this but I know that C# should work

Comment: @MethodMan I did an edin on my original post maybe you can take a look now.

Comment: at this point then it looks like what you want to do is `Serialize` the Class in that case have you looked at any examples here on `Stackoverflow` here is a site as well as a google search you can you to give working examples [Stackoverflow Serialize a Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937630/serialize-class-to-xml)

Comment: [C# Stackoverflow Serialize a Class Google Results](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+stackoverflow+Serialize+Dictionary%3Cstring%2C+List%3C&oq=C%23+stackoverflow+Serialize+Dictionary%3Cstring%2C+List%3C&aqs=chrome..69i57.3198j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23+stackoverflow+Serialize+class)

Comment: @MethodMan I do Serialize the class and it worked perfectly even on IOS the problem started when I added the Dictionary into the mix. I think that the AOT(ahead of time ) compilation cant handle the List<UpgradeData> as the values part of a Dictionary.

Comment: that's why I suggested passing it as an `object` then Casting it does that make sense..?

Comment: You say it works on Windows and MacOS, but doesn't work on another platform (I'm assuming on IOS considering your comment).  Exactly *how* does it not work? Please describe the failure as completely as you can.

Comment: @Steven Hansen The failure is the following. The file is not being created at all ,because I get a ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2<string,System.Collections.generic.List`1<UpgradeData>>

Comment: @MethodMan sorry but it doesnt. Do you want me to cast it as a object before serialization ?

Comment: You should edit your post with the error you get.  Also, you should include any additional information provided by that exception.  You should probably also *attempt* to serialize just a `List<UpgradeData>` list and see if you get the same exception since you suspect that the list is the problem.  Let us know what you discover.

Answer (score 2):

`BinaryFormatter` relies on JIT compilation, which isn't supported on iOS. The problem isn't your data structures, it's the platform feature limitations.

You will have to use a different serialization library which supports full AOT compilation. I've had luck with [JsonFx](https://bitbucket.org/TowerOfBricks/jsonfx-for-unity3d). Some people have recommended [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Comment: By setting `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");` I was able to use the BinaryFormatter for everything else. I need to figure out a way to post the error message from the Ipad.

Comment: You can try serializing simpler types which you stitch back together, but fundamentally you're using a library that is explicitly unsupported on the target platform. I would fix that.

Comment: @ruttwr yes I migrated to using protobuf-net and everything works better now. Still wierd why it only craps out on lists and dictionaries